# Java & SQL comparing dates

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to get client arrival date and compare it with my SQL database to see if in my data base the same date exists. however i receive the following error: `The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String`

P.S I need to compare it via java not using sql query

```
public void makeNewReservation() throws ParseException {
    // Enter informations

    System.out.println("Date of arrivel?");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String date_entree = in.next();
    System.out.println("Date of exit? dd/MM/yyyy");
    String date_sortiee = in.next();
    calculateDaysDifference(date_sortiee, date_entree);



public  void calculateDaysDifference(String date_entree, String date_sortiee) throws ParseException{


ConnectionMySQL myConnection=new ConnectionMySQL();
    Connection conSQL=myConnection.startDBConnection();
    boolean connectionOK=myConnection.checkConnection(conSQL);

    String query = ("SELECT `START_DATE`,`END_DATE` FROM `room_booking");


    //if everything is fine with the connection, i try to execute a query
    if (connectionOK){
        try{
            ResultSet mesResultats=myConnection.executeQuery(conSQL, query);

            //the while loop is just for me to check the dates
            while (mesResultats.next()) {
                System.out.println("START_DATE: "+mesResultats.getString(1)+" END_DATE : "+ mesResultats.getString(2));


                if (date_entree > mesResultats.getString(1){
                    System.out.println("cant reserve room room reserved already");


                }
            }


            // je ferme la connexion
            conSQL.close();

        }

        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }
```

[my data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZiYQ.jpg)

Comment: why can't you compare in the db?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. You have Strings. You're trying to compare them like numbers. Right here: ` if (date_entree > mesResultats.getString(1){` Either convert them, if that's what you want, or use `String.Compare()`

Comment: the teacher wants Java code ! :)

Comment: I'd store it as a DATE in the database, map the value into a java.util.Date, and compare that way.

Comment: the dates in my data base are stored as Date. but before I store the clients dates I must check if there is a room. then I will store them.

Comment: Do you think String.Compare() is the way to go in comparing 2 dates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compare 2 Dates

**1) Convert the input String into Date**

```
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date d=df.format(/*date String*/);

NOTE: df.format will throw parseException if the String format does not match "yyyy-MM-dd" . I leave it upto you to make sure the date string is of the specified format.
```

**2)get Date from sql query**

```
java.util.Date sqlDate=new java.util.Date(resultset.getDate().getTime());

NOTE : resultset.getDate() will give you java.sql.Date class's object.
```

**3) [Compare 2 dates](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)**

Answer (score 3):

try this logic

```
Date date1=new Date(df.parse(mesResultats.getString(1)));
Date date2=new Date(df.parse(mesResultats.getString(2)));

int status=date1.compareTo(date2); //compareto is a function defined for date

if status==0 print same date
if status<0 print  date1 is older then date2
if status>0 print  date1 is newer then date2
```

[Update after comment] 
`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("Format of your date goes here");`

Comment: i am receiving  the error msg: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method parse(String) from the type DateFormat